# Find the key with the most number of elements in the value

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a hash:

```
new_hash = {
  [1] => [2, 3, 4],
  [2] => [3],
  [3] => [5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  [4] => [],
}
```

I want to select the key that has the most number of elements, i.e., the third key.

I tried code but it gave me a "no method error". Can anyone advise me on this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When asking for help we need to see your attempt to solve the problem. Please read  "[ask]".

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
hash.max_by{|k,v| v.length}.first
# => returns [3] if your hash is {[1] => [2,3,4], [2] => [3], [3] => [5,6,7,8,9], [4] => []}
```

The `first` method is used because `hash.max_by{|k,v| v.length}` returns a 2-element array of the structure `[key, value]`. So we run `first` on it to fetch the key. If you wanted it in a hash format, you could do:

```
Hash[hash.max_by{|k,v| v.length}]
# => returns { [3] => [5, 6, 7, 8, 9] }
```

And per your comment, if you want to use `select`:

```
max_value = hash.values.map(&:length).max
hash.select{|k, v| v.length == max_value}
# => returns {[3] => [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]}, but if you had other values with 5 elements, the returned hash will include them too
```

Comment: Thanks alot! it worked, but whats the difference between hash.max_by and hash.select?

Comment: `hash.select{...}` applies a filter on the hash to select all the members of the hash that the select block returned true for them. So if you knew what the max length was, you could do something like: `hash.select{|k, v| v.length == max_length}`. However, it will return all members with that maximum length. `max_by` saves you the need to know the max length in advance, and also returns a single element.

Comment: Sure, I also updated the answer to include this. It all depends on what you'd like the result to be in duplicate scenario.

Comment: sorry to trouble but I do have another question, this is really the first time i have tried ruby so I'm pretty lousy in this,

after I have the hash key which contains the most number of people, can I remove the duplicated elements in each key?

Based on the example above, ignoring key"3" if I were to select key 1, I would like to duplicated value in key 1 from the entire hashmap.
Since key 1 is choosen , values are 2,3 & 4 thus I would delete "3" from key 2

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand, but if you want to remove the elements that were found in the key with the most number of elements and keep the hash structure intact, then try this:
`key_with_most_elements = hash.max_by{|k,v| v.length}.first` - e.g. [1]
`elements_array = hash.delete(key_with_most_elements)` - e.g. [2,3,4]
`hash_without_found_elements = Hash[hash.map{|k,v| [k, v - elements_array] }`]

Note that `hash.delete` is destructive, so it will remove [1] from the hash.

Comment: ZhenLiang, if this answer fully addressed your question and helped conclude the issue, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score -1):

Say,

```
your_hash = { '1': [2, 3, 4], '2': [3], '3': [5, 6, 7, 8, 9], '4': [], '5': [6, 7, 8, 9, 13], '00': [1, 3] }
```

If you want all pairs with the max value, you can do this:

```
max = your_hash.values.max_by {|a| a.length}.size
your_hash.select { |k, v| v.length == max }
# => {:"3"=>[5, 6, 7, 8, 9], :"5"=>[6, 7, 8, 9, 13]}
```

To get the keys of the hash that has the max length array:

```
   Hash[your_hash.select { |k, v| v.length == max}].keys
   # => [:"3", :"5"]
```

Comment: K, you don't need to convert to a hash, as `Hash#select` (not `Enumerable#select`) is being invoked.

Comment: Note that the OP requested the key with the most number of elements, i.e. the values are assumed to be arrays and you need to use `length` on them.

Comment: yes, I updated the answer just before seeing your comment @AmitA

Comment: `your_hash.values.length` isn't going to tell you what you think it does. It's _not_ the length of the longest array. Run your code against the OP's hash and then add some additional hash elements and rerun it.

Comment: @theTinMan would you consider revoking the `down vote` (if you gave that) as I have updated my answer and it's producing the correct results to the OPs question? Thanks.